# The best tools money can buy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In my company (which scored 3/12 on the [Joel Test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html)) we have access to free software only, so I was wondering what, in the Java EE world, are the best tools money can buy?

For instance, I was painfully debugging some HQL with [p6spy](http://www.p6spy.com/) when someone told me about [hibernate profiler](http://hibernateprofiler.com/), which is really great and helpful.  And I started to think "there is a world beyond free/open source!"

If you have the chance working with the best tools (including free/open source), what were they?  Could you live without them?  How did they improve your life and your productivity?

Profilers, designers, frameworks, graphical components, and other tools are welcome.

Comment: This question by its nature has no one "right" answer; would you mark it "community wiki" please?

Comment: "the best tools money can buy" is a euphemism.  It is legitimate to ask what it means.  I vote to re-open.

Comment: Seems to be a popular question so voting to re-open

Comment: @edg @willcodejavaforfood This doesn't make this question less subjective.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent - It is subjective, but I think we can still get useful answers from it and I don't see much scope for arguments

Comment: At least make it CW ... It's just an open-discussion after all.

Comment: If you are 3/12 on the Joel test, then "Do you use the best tools money can buy?" is probably the least of your problems. I feel the questions on his list are also in order of importance.

Comment: @Pascal: Subjective alone isn't enough to close a question, just look at the close reason, where's the OP being argumentative here? @willcode: Popular being a good reason to reopen leaves me.. just.. *\*speechless\**

Comment: I wish there was more answers, like tools for tests, perf, or graphical components (stock charts and stuff) etc..

Answer (score 12):

There's no such thing as the best tools money can buy.

No, it's a euphemism for an attitude that rejects the false-economy of putting up with inferior tools for the sake of bean-counting.

Comment: Well said, This is the only 'test' I disagree with in the Joel test.

Comment: @LiraNuna, edg didn't say he disagreed with it.  He was pointing out what the rule is really suppose to mean.

Answer (score 9):

Starting with the basics...

I like eclipse, but I really enjoyed working with [IDEA IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

Answer (score 5):

**Source Control**

Personally, I don't see any huge disadvantage in going with either Subversion or Git, depending on the way your team does things. Perforce is usually the preferred pay option however.

**Issue Tracking**

This is one area where I really think commercial solutions shine. I'm an unapologetic JIRA fanboy, particularly when it's combined with GreenHopper for a very robust agile project management / issue tracking suite.

Answer (score 5):

An example would be Visual Studio and [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/).

But it's all subjective. I think what Joel meant is:

1. Pretend everything is free.
2. Choose the software you want to use.
3. If it costs, pay for it.

Answer (score 4):

I'd argue that in many cases the best tools "money can buy" are actually the open source ones... but that aside, I have a few votes for good commercial tools:

Java Profilers:

- [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)
- [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/overview/index.jsp)

I've had licenses for both, and very slighly prefer JProfiler, but they're both very good, IMO.

Code reviews:

- [Code Collaborator](http://smartbear.com/codecollab.php)

Excellent for organizing and executing code reviews.

Comment: Should we assume that you can't buy FOSS tools, or that you can buy them, but the price is just $0?

Answer (score 3):

Some of the tools we use:

- [IntelliJ (IDE)](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)
- [Structure101 (code analysis/design)](http://www.headwaysoftware.com/products/structure101/index.php)
- [Pulse (continuous integration)](http://zutubi.com/"Pulse)
- [YourKit (profiling)](http://www.yourkit.com/"YourKit")

Answer (score 2):

Oracle database

Answer (score 1):

YourKit and JIRA are worth every penny. I haven't used any open-source software that comes close to these.

Answer (score -6):

For me, one of the best investement ever was my pro-account at [rememberthemilk.com](http://www.rememberthemilk.com) in combination with my android mobile.

And for those who want "tools" only: The [Omondo-UML-Plugin](http://www.uml2.org/) for Eclipse is what I wish I had money for.

Comment: How does this help you with Java EE development?

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood So I should mention paper and pen?

Comment: @Pascal Thivent - If you wish

Comment: @Pascal Thivent: well, as a matter of fact you can get both for free. especially pens. :)

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood and Pascal Thivent:

Indeed, making me more organised. What's wrong with that? Don't be so tool fixed!

To quote the OP: "This question is not meant as a contest for the best tool in the world, I really just want to know what tools you use and why you couldn't live without, or how it improved your developper life or your productivity etc.."

Got it now?

Comment: @bitschnau - Never said there was anything wrong with your answer. I just stated the obvious to Pascal's question :)

Comment: I **do** like RTM but the question is not about any tool, it's about Java EE development related tools. Quoting the OP: *in the Java EE world, what are the best tools money can buy ?* Got it now?

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood: Sorry, got it wrong.
@Pascal Thivent: Let's not argue about this. I think we made our points clear and for your convenience I added a more JEE related tool. :-)
PS: Let's start a question in the community wiki, concerning the point: Where does the Java EE world start and where does it end? :-D